# Enabling auto-fill-mode only when document already filled

Tags: auto-fill-mode

I have `turn-on-auto-fill` as part of my `text-mode-hook`. This works great for new documents, but when I open a buffer that is not filled with hard breaks I rarely want to start doing so to a single paragraph just because I make one edit to the buffer.

Is there a way to scan the whole buffer after opening to see whether it already is auto-filled? And turn on `auto-fill-mode` in that case but leave it off otherwise?

I've searched EmacsWiki and MELPA Stable and didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Since there's no one, objective way to decide "file is/is not already auto-filled," you'll need to decide on some heuristics that Emacs can use to decide if the file is "sufficiently" auto-filled to count it as such.  For example: if *any* paragraph has a newline within it, does it count?  If *any* paragraph has, say, more than 80 characters between newlines, does it count?  Once you've decided what heuristic to use, it shouldn't be hard to tell Emacs to apply it.

Comment: The heuristic I had in mind is if you ran `fill-region` on the whole buffer, would the contents change? If no, then the buffer is already auto-filled, and `auto-fill-mode` should be enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work: `fill-region` will modify the buffer even if it makes no actual changes.  Aside from that, if your `fill-column` value differs even a little from that used when the file was last modified, you'll get changes even though it's already been auto-filled.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman what you can do is to write a function that count char length per line and compare to the value of `fill-colomn`